# Sitecore Content deliveries and Solr with High availability

Tags: solr, solution-architecture

I'm trying to find a recommendation from Sitecore in terms of configuring Solr for high availability and how to use it properly with Sitecore. Does anybody know where I can find it?
If not, I'm considering these options, any preference or alternative?

### Master-Slave:

Is it still "valid" or is it deprecated since SolrCloud?
In this case, How should I configure Sitecore on each role to use one server for indexing, and another (load balanced servers) for querying?

### Zookeeper:

How many instances do I really need? I understand (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694296/using-zookeeper-with-solr-but-only-have-2-servers)) that I need 3 Zookeepers minimum to keep the cluster running if one goes down, but apparently they should not be on the same machine as the actual Solr instances meaning I need 5 instances (3 ZK and 2 Solr). And again, Or should I configure Sitecore to use the cluster properly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We are using Zookeeper with Sitecore 8.1 Update 2, and as per the documentation here: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html we are using 3 instances. This is the minimum required.

> Three ZooKeeper servers is the minimum recommended size for an ensemble, and we also recommend that they run on separate machines.

This works really well for us and ensures no downtime when indexes are being rebuilt.

This is an excellent blog post that we followed to set this up:

http://www.chrissulham.com/sitecore-on-solr-cloud-part-2/

**A note of caution though as pointed out by Grant Killian in the comments below:**

> Note: SolrCloud setups are under experimental support starting from
>   Sitecore XP 8.2, meaning some issues are possible. In case of related
>   issues, Sitecore Support will help with troubleshooting, while there
>   is no guarantee that a fix will be available. In earlier versions of
>   Sitecore CMS/XP only standalone Solr setups are supported.

**more info here:** [kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897](http://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897)

We carried out the following process to install this on our 3 Solr Search Servers in Production:

1. Download Solr 5.2.1 (i'd recommend Solr 5.1 though as Sitecore support will help with issues for Sc 8.2: [kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897](http://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897))
2. Prepare Solr configuration for Sitecore Indexes - Steps 1, 2, 3 and 4.
3. Configuring ZooKeeper ensemble - Steps 1-5
4. Configuring SolrCloud with ZooKeeper ensemble - All Steps
5. Upload index configuration into ZooKeeper - All Steps
6. Create collections

**Here are some commands you might find useful:**

**Registering Config:**

```
zkcli -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd upconfig -confdir D:\Solr\server\solr\configsets\sitecore_configs\conf -confname scbasic
```

**Creating a Collection:**

```
solr create -c sitecore -d D:\Solr\server\solr\configsets\sitecore_configs -n scbasic -shards 1 -replicationFactor 1 -p 8983
```

**Add replica to collection:**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=ADDREPLICA&collection=sitecore&shard=shard1&node=172.16.128.32:8983_solr
```

**Remove replica from collection:**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETEREPLICA&collection=collection1&shard=shard1&replica=core_node1
```

I wrote some PowerShell scripts to do most of the above for me so I could run them on Staging and Production and I found this easier than calling the API manually.

The script loops round an array of the sitecore index names. The Core is created on one of the Solr Servers and then 2 replica cores are created on the other two Solr servers.

```
$SitecoreIndexNames = @('sitecore_core_index', 'sitecore_master_index', 'sitecore_web_index', 'sitecore_analytics_index', 'sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master', 'sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web', 'sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master', 'sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web', 'sitecore_testing_index', 'sitecore_suggested_test_index', 'sitecore_fxm_master_index', 'sitecore_fxm_web_index', 'sitecore_list_index', 'social_messages_master', 'social_messages_web')
```

**Here are the key functions:**

```
function Create-SolrCore($solrBaseUrl, $coreName, $configSet, $solrCollectionName, $solrConfigSetName) {
        $restUrl = "{0}/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name={1}&property.name={1}&collection={1}&collection.configName={3}&numShards=1&shard=shard1" -f $solrBaseUrl, $coreName, $solrCollectionName, $solrConfigSetName

        Write-Host "adding core: $restUrl"
        $result1 = Invoke-WebRequest $restUrl -Method GET -UseBasicParsing
        Write-Host "Created Solr core $coreName."
    }

function Create-Replica($solrBaseUrl, $coreName, $configSet, $solrCollectionName, $solrConfigSetName, $replicataIP) {
    $restReplicaUrl = "{0}/admin/collections?action=ADDREPLICA&collection={1}&property.name={1}&numShards=1&shard=shard1&node={2}" -f $solrBaseUrl, $coreName, $replicataIP
    Write-Host "adding replica: $restReplicaUrl"
    $result2 = Invoke-WebRequest $restReplicaUrl -Method GET -UseBasicParsing
    Write-Host "Created replica for $SolrCollectionName."
}

function Create-Replicas($indexNames, $nonSwitchOnRebuildIndexNames, $coreNamePrefix, $baseUrl) {

    $SitecoreIndexNames | % {
        $index = Convert-SitecoreIndexNameToCoreName($_)

        try {
            Create-Replica $SolrBaseUrl $index $SolrConfigSetName $SolrCollectionName $SolrConfigSetName $ReplicataIP

        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Unable to add replica for core $index. $_"
        }
    }
}


function Create-SolrCores($indexNames, $nonSwitchOnRebuildIndexNames, $coreNamePrefix, $baseUrl) {

    $SitecoreIndexNames | % {
        $index = Convert-SitecoreIndexNameToCoreName($_)
        try {
            Create-SolrCore $SolrBaseUrl $index $SolrConfigSetName $SolrCollectionName $SolrConfigSetName

        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Unable to create core for $index index. This probably means it already exists. $_"
        }
    }
}
```

> I based these on Kam's Solr Cannon Scripts:
>   http://kamsar.net/index.php/2016/03/The-Solr-Cannon/

**Once you have done this you can point Sitecore at the Solr ensemble like so:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <settings>
            <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress">
                <patch:attribute name="value">http://{ipofinstance}:8983/solr</patch:attribute>
            </setting>
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Really good post series: So the short answer is: Minimum 3 servers behind a load balancer, each of them with Solr and Zookeeper. Configure Sitecore to use load balancer's end point. Right?

Comment: Yeah, I've added more info above to help you but thats the crux of it. Works well for us so far.

Comment: I've added some of my Powershell scripts for you above too Vincent.

Comment: Are you concerned with what Sitecore will officially support, or comfortable using "experimental" approaches?  Refer to https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897 to see what I'm getting at.  There are, of course, options running "in the wild" that function fine but are not formally supported.  That may or may not matter in your case, but I wanted to point this out.

Comment: Killian - that is certainly something to consider. Especially for those on older versions of Sitecore. We are planning on upgrading to 8.2 in the next week or two so should be covered for any support issues regarding search once we are. We may need to downgrade slightly to Solr 5.1 though. I'll update my answer to include some info on this.

Comment: I'll add that if you can't separate Zookeeper and Solr on separate servers, I suggest that you at least try to have isolated disk volumes for their storage.

Zookeeper is very fussy about read/write latency and issues with it can be pretty random and scary. Things like nodes randomly dropping offline etc.

Comment: This is a great guide, thanks. Can I just clarify that if you want to use separate servers for zookeeper and solr, you need 3x zookeeper server and 3x solr server, and zookeeper needs to be installed on all 6, but only as a client on the solr servers? Or is zookeeper client already bundled as part of solr?

Comment: No problem. As far as I am aware if you wanted to install Zookeeper on it's own server then you would need 3 server for Zookeeper and 3 for Solr. However I'm not sure why you would want to do this as Zookeeper is fairly low in resource usage so should be fine running on the Solr server along-side Solr.