# How to use Sitecore SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex on Solr slave Indexes which are replicated from Master Index

Tags: solr, content-search

The following is our master/slave configuration by using Solr replication.

Here is the image which depicts our configuration:

[image]

**SOLR-master** is connected to the CM instance. When the CM rebuilds the `sitecore_web_index` the Solr-master instance is doing all of the processing.

**SOLR-slave** is connected to the CD instance. You can either have each instance of the CD talk directly to a slave instance or you can connect them to a load balancer (F5/Netscaler/etc.). The Solr-slave instances poll at some interval (perhaps 60 seconds); If the Solr-master has completed a commit/startup then the Solr-slave instances will replicate the files.

Can I use Sitecore `SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex` on slave indexes which are replicated from Master? Is there any other alternatives without breaking search on CD which uses Slave indexes?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what version of Sitecore you are using but have you looked at Solr Cloud?

To my knowledge you shouldn’t need switchonrebuild with Solr cloud as I believe Zookeeper should manage the core availability during index updates.

There is a good guide here:

https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/Install-and-configure-SolrCloud/

And here:

http://www.chrissulham.com/sitecore-on-solr-cloud-part-1/

There are lots of configuration options that you can set so read the guides over carefully.

> update

I also wrote answer here for how to setup SolrCloud that might be useful for you: 
[Sitecore Content deliveries and Solr with High availability](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/sitecore-content-deliveries-and-solr-with-high-availability)

Comment: Version:   Sitecore 8.2 u4
Solr 5.1

Comment: Ty Adam. We are using Sitecore 8.2 u4 and Solr 5.1. We have Master-Slave Model. Do we have to upgrade to solrcloud to use zookeeper? Can we use existing master/slave model and add a zookeeper for fail over?

Comment: No SolrCloud is the replacement for the master/slave approach and is the recommended approach now for scaling and distributed search see here for the old docs and note about this from Solr: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/distributed-search-with-index-sharding.html#distributed-search-with-index-sharding. The Solr Cloud docs are here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/solrcloud.html. I will also update my answer with a link to a post I wrote regarding setting up SolrCloud.

Comment: You actually do need SwitchOnRebuild with SolrCloud as well. SwitchOnRebuild is for solving the Sitecore command of "rebuildindex" which will delete all documents in the core and reindex all. SolrCloud does not help solving this

Comment: Hi Klaus, I think this depends on your version of Sitecore / Solr as I believe that SwitchOnRebuild wasn't/isn't supported on certain version. I was trying to find a link where I'd seen this but I can't currently. There was a patch for certain versions of Sitecore here to resolve this but it looks to have since been removed: https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.449298%C2%A0